# what is an easy / easiest way to *plot* a std::vector<double>?

Tags: c++, opencv, plot, computer-vision

I'm looking for something like:

```
 std::vector<double> X = some_math_function( );
 somenamespace :: plot(  Wrapper( X ) ); // pop-up and display a graph of X on y-axis, 1 to X.size() on x-axis.
```

Obviously there are heavier-weight methods like setting up gnu-plot or whatever, and I've used the stuff in VTK charts. I just want a stupid, ghetto, plot to appear. This is for coarse debug checking things like "is the vector even changing? does it suddenly jerk when I move the camera?" and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to OpenCV.

Comment: It is not specific to opencv but 1) The data stream is from opencv functions and 2) opencv allows displaying an *image* easily, so a hacky solution is to write the vector into an empty image, making a very ghetto plot function.

Answer (score 6):

If this is for debugging why not just output the vector to a delimited file and plot in excel or gnuplot or something as a separate step?

so something like

```
//untested
ofstream myfilestream("myfile");
std::copy(X.begin(), X.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(myfilestream, '\n');
```

then just plot the file in what ever tool you like e.g.

```
gnuplot
plot "myfile" with lines
```

Comment: Well that wont work for a fast stream of data in X. About to roll my own plotter using OpenCV imshow() since it already links in...

Comment: How much data are we talking about? if the stream of data is fast, the writes just need to be buffered enough to cope with this. obviously at some speed and quantity this breaks down but are you really in that situation?

Comment: but would gnuplot 'watch' the temp file in that case? Or do you mean I should invoke a shell and do $watch -n 0.2 "gnuplot -onelinearg? \"myfile\" with lines"

Comment: no, I meant dump all the data in one step then plot it as a additional step after your test, if you need to correlate the plot with when you where physically doing things output a time too. i.e. treat it as a logging exercise

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library) seems to have quite a few suggestions on the matter. I haven't seen anything that stands out as a simple library for the purposes you want.

Here are a few lightweight examples, but it seems to me that if you've got to learn enough to stand up *any* library, you may as well stand up a respected one like gnuplot. In many cases the time you lose by having to deal with a more complex library is more than made up for by the community support and (relative) bugless..ness... of a more mature product.

[koolplot](http://koolplot.codecutter.org/)

[GOBLIN](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) (cross-platform GPL plotting library). The code look as

```
mglGraphZB gr;// create canvas
mglData d; d.Set(X);  // convert to internal format
gr.YRange(d); // set range for y-axis
gr.Plot(d);   // plot it
gr.Axis();    // draw axis if you need
gr.WritePNG("1.png"); // save it
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C++11: I would recommend using [matplotlibcpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) which uses python for plots. The library is REALLY straightforward to use and you only need to copy the header file in your repository.

The code would looks like:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // for std::iota

int main()
{
  std::vector <double> y = {0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.6};
  std::vector <int> x(y.size());
  std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);

  matplotlibcpp::plot(x, y);
  matplotlibcpp::show();
  plt::save("plot.png");
}
```

In your `cmake` :

```
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7)
target_include_directories(myproject PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myproject ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Or pass it to directly to your compiler:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

Answer (score -1):

I remember being easy to plot curves with [gd](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) in php, but that was a long time ago.